# Can a single instance of WSO2 CEP Siddhi use several cores?

Tags: wso2, apache-storm, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have an instance of WSO2 CEP running in a Linux machine with 8 cores. I have 30-40 Input streams with nearly 200 execution plans. My problem is that when I insert events, only one CPU gets busy at a time. Busy core changes but I can't make the eight cores work at the same time, affecting drastically to the performance and scalability.

Is there any configuration item I am missing or do I need to configure Siddhi in cluster mode with Storm?

Comment: Can you specify the throughput of the events? Do you event receivers (like wso2event or http) to publish events to WSO2CEP?

Comment: Hi Tharik, we are receiving 200 events per second with near 100 fields/attributes per event. We do use wso2event and publish in WSO2CEP v4.2.0. Once the different execution plans are triggered, they are published in Log and/or the WSO2 Context Broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEP in Storm is there to support distributed processing. For your scenario, you don't really need to set it up with Storm. You can try using `async` annotation within your execution plans so that it'll buffer the events and use a different thread for subsequent execution. Refer to the following test: [AsyncTestCase](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/3.1.x/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/managment/AsyncTestCase.java)

Comment: Thanks Grainier, performance is definitely better! We need to check that order is preserved but it really seems promising. Does this configuration preserves the order of messages?